# What is happening while instantiating an abstract class? What is an anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

What is happening while instantiating class Person? What is an anonymous inner class?

```
abstract class Person {
    abstract void eat();
}

class TestAnonymousInner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person p = new Person() {
            void eat() {
                System.out.println("nice fruits");
            } // what happens here?
        };
        p.eat();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you should start by googling *anonymous inner class* and come back if you got a problem. This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) may help.

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/presentation/270252505/Interfaces-and-Inner-Classes

Comment: actually i came from there only...i still don't get it.. how compiler gives the name when i already given TestAnonymousInner  as my inner class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous classes are really just syntactic sugar.

Since `Person` is abstract, you can't directly create an instance of `Person`. You must create an instance of a class that inherits `Person`. That's how abstract classes are designed.

However, sometimes it's quite inconvenient to create a subclass of `Person` when you want to use this class. You have to write something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person p = new PersonSubclass();
        p.eat();
    }
}  

class PersonSubclass extends Person {
    void eat() {
       System.out.println("nice fruits");
    }
}
```

People reading your code has to find the declaration of `PersonSubclass` in order to know what the code does.

But let's think about the root of the problem: the reason why you can't create an instance of `Person` is because `eat` does not have a method body. So if you create a method body for `eat`, you can "kind of" create an instance of `Person`. And this is what anonymous classes are. They allow you to create instances of abstract classes/interfaces just by writing method bodies. That's why the above code can just be written like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Person p = new Person() {
        void eat() {
            System.out.println("nice fruits");
        }
    };
    p.eat();
}
```

It's much shorter and easier to read, isn't it?

What is really happening here then?

The compiler creates a subclass of `Person` for you, as an inner class of the enclosing class. And in that subclass, there is your method body for `eat`. The inner class is given a very special name (I can't remember what though) so that normal code can't access it.

P.S. In Java 8, lambdas are introduced. They are again syntactic sugar for interfaces with only one method. This does not work with abstract classes though.

Comment: so in anonymous inner class i have to define all abstract method while creating instanace of outer class?

Comment: No, not the outer class. It's just whatever class you want to create an instance of. In this case, it's `Person` @HarishAmarnath

Answer (score 0):

`Person` is `abstract` so you can't instantiate it ; but by injecting an implementation for the `abstract` method during the instantiation, `Person` become "instantiatable" ; and at the end an invocation of `eat()` is done and the result will be : `eat()` => `nice fruits`

Answer (score 0):

Actually **Anonymous Inner class** is the way to *declare* and *instantiate* a class at same time. They are as any other classes except do not having a name. Whenever you declare an **Inner class** whatever it is **Anonymous** or not, Compiler creates an internal class for that class. Like what is happening here is, Compiler creates a internal class like below

```
static class TestAnonymousInner$1 extends Person  
{  
   TestAnonymousInner$1(){}  
   void eat()  
    {  
        System.out.println("nice fruits");  
    }  
}
```

you can see this is just like any other local classes. But as `Person` is  an `abstract` class, it cannot be instantiated without extending. Thats why compiler created internal class is of type `extends Person`