# How can we call methods overridden in a java anonymous class?

Tags: java, anonymous, anonymous-class

Consider the code below :

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
  abstract m1();
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    AbstractClass obj = new AbstractClass() {
      @Override void m1() { 
        System.out.print("Instance of abstract class !");
      }
    };
    obj.m1();
  }
}
```

Now here is what I did not understand about this code.
I read that anonymous class creates the class with unknown name which extends the class whose reference is provided (here it is abstract AbstractClass).

Also I remember that we cannot implement the method of child class if the the object is having reference of parent class.

see block of code below

```
Parent obj = new Child();
obj.methodOfParent();
obj.methodOfChild();  //this gives error
```

Now here is my point if *Anonymous Class* extends its *Parent Class* whose reference is provided, then how can we call overriden methods of Parent Class from Anonymous Class?

Comment: This is pretty unclear - are you asking why it's possible to do `obj.m1()`?

Comment: Yes, @Oliver Charlesworth

Comment: This is an incredibly unclear question. But one thing that should be pointed out is that `Parent obj = new Child();
obj.methodOfParent();` will call the methodOfParent of your Child class (Which it either inherits from the Parent or overrides and provides a new implementation).

Comment: On *"we cannot implement the method of child class if the the object is having reference of parent class"* -- do you mean you can't *call* a method that's only in the child class through a variable of the parent class type? [Note that no Java variable is an object -- they're either primitives or references to objects.]

Comment: If your question is why you cannot call any methods from the anonymous class, but only methods defined in the parent/interface, then the answer is: because your reference of that type. In your code, you have a reference `Parent obj`. Therefore, you can only call methods defined in `Parent` through this reference. This has nothing to do with abstract classes, but with inheritance.

Comment: Copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492238/what-is-happening-while-instantiating-an-abstract-class-what-is-an-anonymous-in/43492372

Comment: @Turing85, my bad, I red to fast.

Comment: "Also I remember that we cannot implement the method of child class if the the object is having reference of parent class." Sense made: none.

Comment: Looks, like there is conflict in the way others and I understanding​ this question. The second snippet of code is just for clearing my idea it has no significant relationship with the actual code right at the top. Okay forget everything but can you simply explain why anonymous class works ?

Comment: @PreetPatel you can invoke the overriden methods , they are the methods defined in parent class with modified behavior, they are not additional methods. Read an answer ts quite clear and well written http://stackoverflow.com/a/43547871/504133

Comment: The answer to the question is:  you can't.  If you introduce new methods in the anonymous class, then you can only call them from within the anonymous class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between calling an overridden method of parent and calling a method of child. If a method is declared in class `T`, you can call it on a variable statically typed as `T`, regardless of where the method is actually implemented.

In your example, if `obj.methodOfParent()` happens to be a method override from `Child`, the method in `Child` will run, even though `obj`'s static type is `Parent`.

Same mechanism is in play with anonymous classes: the reason that you are allowed to call `obj.m1()` is that `m1()` has been declared in the parent class.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you just miss one point. Let me show you example:

```
class Parent {
  public void methodOfParent() {}
  public void methodOfParentToBeOverriden() {}
}
class Child extends Parent {
  @Override public void methodOfParentToBeOverriden() {}
  public void methodOfChild() {}
}

Parent obj = new Child();
obj.methodOfParent(); //this is OK
obj.methodOfParentToBeOverriden(); // this is OK too
obj.methodOfChild();  //this gives error  
((Child)obj).methodOfChild();  //this is OK too here.
```

Please note that when you call `obj.methodOfParentToBeOverriden()` it will be called implementation from Child class. Independence did you cast this object to Parent type or not.